# Put image picture when doing "GOOGLE SEARCH" as cnn does

Tags: html, image

I am building site.

I want to add ability to show an image beside the site+description when I am doing GOOGLE search, and see my site on organic GOOGLE search results.

i.e - https://www.google.co.il/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=8kzeU_mAFsOH4AaG6ID4AQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=cnn shows the result with a picture beside the site+description.

I tried to make a sample, as advised by webmaster tool, like follwing:

```
<img itemprop="image" ...>
```

but the above doesn't work (When I am searching by 'google search' image is not shown).

Thanks :)

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible. You may have to speak to google as this is no longer part of your site, rather Google's

Comment: it's called knowledge graph; http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/search/knowledge.html

Comment: I am not sure - I have seen this not just for CNN. Even it is paid, but I think this kind of behavior is done by webmaster tool. I would like some guidelines, since I have searched a lot, and didn't find a clue doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does that stuff based on social networks, You would want to create a google+/facebook/twitter page for the site and upload a profile image there.

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/175288?hl=en

Also you will want to confirm your domain ownership with google webmaster tools
http://www.google.com/webmasters/

All of these things increase the chance for your site getting a image next to it. BUT it is still determined by google's algorithms so it can take a while.

Comment: Do you mean that cnn has google+ that change from time to time? I presume other sites has that ability too. How they do that?

Comment: See the following links (at the second link (webmastertools), you can choose the recipe, and see the image). https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1626955?hl=en
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fallrecipes.com%2Frecipe%2Fbanana-banana-bread%2F   Nevertheless, I didn't succeed doing above.

Comment: It can take a while for it to take effect. Googlebot has to crawl and group everything together.